# Objective-C How to update subview's content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not using the UIBuilder.  I have programmatically added two subviews to the main view.  I can see them if I add background color to them.  However, I want to set the value of the two subviews to images.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *firstImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *secondImage;
.
.
.
self.firstImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 89, 156, 78)];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstImage];

self.secondImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(161, 89, 156, 78)];
[self.view addSubview:self.secondImage];
.
.
.
self.leftView.image = self.firstImage;
self.rightView.image = self.secondImage;
```

My images are not displaying.  Is there something I need to do to hook them up since I'm not using the UIBuilder?  I am grateful for any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What are `self.leftView` and `self.rightView`? They are not defined in the code you have provided

Comment: `self.firstImage` and `self.secondImage` aren't UIImage.

Comment: Where do you initializing your images? Your class is UIView with no content.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine leftView and rightView are UIImageView instances. but firstImage and secondImage are UIView instances.

you need to make firstImage and secondImage instances of UIImage and initialize them as follows.

```
firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
```

After this instead of `[self.view addSubView:]` You have to make `self.leftView.image = firstImage`

And finally you can add `[self.view addSubview:self.leftView];`

Do the same for right view and second image and you are done it will be useful if you can show your views hierarchies or the layout of what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be following:

Properly declare your properties. They are should be of [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, since you want to display the images.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *firstImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *secondImage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *leftImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *rightImageView;
```

Carefully initialize your images, put the exact names of your images. `-imageNamed:`
is case sensitive to the names.

```
self.firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"];
self.secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImage.png"];
```

Setting initial image that should our instance `leftImageView` show and frame, adding it as a subview of our `self.view`.

```
self.leftImageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:self.firstImage];
self.leftImageView.frame = CGRectMake(3, 89, 156, 78);
[self.view addSubview:self.leftImageView];
```

The same operation with the second image.

```
self.rightImageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:self.secondImage];
self.rightImageView.frame = CGRectMake(161, 89, 156, 78)];
[self.view addSubview:self.rightImageView];
```